# Generate an arbitrary number of process substitutions as tee arguments

Tags: bash

I'm using this code in a bash script. I use it to transfer a source folder to multiple destinations:

```
cd /Volumes/ ; tar cf - SOURCE/  | tee \
>( cd /Volumes/dest1 ; tar xf - ) \
>( cd /Volumes/dest2 ; tar xf - ) \
> /dev/null
```

This command works well. I want to set the destinations at the beginning of the script. So the number of destinations can vary.

For example the destinations can be in a var or an array:

```
destinationList=/Volumes/dest1 /Volumes/dest2
cd /Volumes/Untitled/ ; tar cf - SOURCE/  | tee \
# for item in destinationList
# do
#     add this code ">( cd $item ; tar xf - )"
# done
> /dev/null
```

Is there a nice way to do it?

Comment: I'd rather title this "Generate an arbitrary number of process substitutions as tee arguments" -- passing extra arguments to `tee` is easy in general; it's making those arguments be process substitutions that's tricky.

Comment: I edited the title

Comment: BTW, note `cd "$1" && tar` instead of `cd "$1"; tar` in my answer -- you don't want `tar` to run if the `cd` failed and thus the current directory is somewhere other than your intended destination. (This is actually a bug that http://shellcheck.net/ will catch).

Comment: `/Volumes` implies that you're on MacOS -- note that Apple ships an ancient version of bash because they're not willing to agree to the GPLv3 license that modern releases are shipped under; you might want to install a current bash with [MacPorts](https://macports.org/) (my preference), or [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a case where `eval` is one of the easier options, though it needs to be very used very carefully.

```
unpackInDestinations() {
  local dest currArg='' evalStr=''
  for dest; do
    printf -v currArg '>(cd %q && exec tar xf -)' "$dest"
    evalStr+=" $currArg"
  done
  eval "tee $evalStr >/dev/null"
}

tar cf - SOURCE/ | unpackInDestinations /Volumes/dest{1,2}
```

---

Less efficiently (but without, perhaps, causing anyone trying to audit the code's security as much consternation), one can also write a recursive function:

```
unpackInDestinations() {
  local dest
  if (( $# == 0 )); then
    cat >/dev/null
  elif (( $# == 1 )); then
    cd "$1" && tar xf -
  else
    dest=$1; shift
    tee >(cd "$dest" && exec tar xf -) | unpackInDestinations "$@"
  fi
}
```

The number of `tee`s this creates varies with the number of arguments, so it's substantially less efficient than the hand-written code or the `eval`-based equivalent to same.

---

If you only need to support new versions of bash (the below requires *at least* 4.1), there's some additional magic available that can provide the best of both worlds:

```
unpackInDestinations() {
  local -a dest_fds=( ) args=( )
  local arg fd_num retval

  # open a file descriptor for each argument
  for arg; do
    exec {fd_num}> >(cd "$arg" && exec tar xf -)
    dest_fds+=( "$fd_num" )
    args+=( "/dev/fd/$fd_num" )
  done

  tee "${args[@]}" >/dev/null; retval=$?

  # close the FDs
  for fd_num in "${dest_fds[@]}"; do
    exec {fd_num}>&-
  done

  # and return the exit status we got from tee
  return "$retval"
}
```

Comment: I did not know about named file descriptors.  I sure hope I remember about that when I find out I need this.  Could the variable used be local (it does not seem to be in the code above)?